# Cannot install python interface for shogun

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, shogun

I am trying to install a python interface for Machine Learning toolbox "Shogun". I have downloaded `shogun-4.1.0.tar.bz2`, extracted it, went there and (according to http://shogun-toolbox.org/doc/en/latest/install.html) executed:

```
mkdir build && cd build && cmake -DPythonModular=ON .. && make && sudo make install
```

Everything went fine.
Now To check if its working:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=SHOGUN_INSTALL_DIR/lib &&
export PYTHONPATH=SHOGUN_INSTALL_DIR/lib/pythonX.Y/dist-packages/ &&
python examples/undocumented/python_modular/graphical/svm.py
```

The problem is that the last step raises error, there is no folder `graphical` within the `python_modular`.
Have anyone tried this toolbox before?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to bother you, I have found that the files are moved and the text  at the link above is out of date. If anyone would have such problem - look here: https://github.com/shogun-toolbox/shogun/issues/3110